# Snake game wall collision not working correctly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

currently I am trying to code a snake game in Python using the turtle module. Right now I am having issues with detecting collision with the wall and the snake head.

```
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
import time


def main():
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.title("Snake Game")
    screen.tracer(0)

    scoreboard = Scoreboard()
    scoreboard.display_score()

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()

    screen.listen()
    screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
    screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
    screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
    screen.onkey(snake.right, "Right")

    still_playing = True
    while still_playing:
        screen.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        snake.move()

        # Detect collision with food.
        if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
            food.refresh()
            scoreboard.increase_score()

        # Detect collision with wall.
        if snake.has_hit_wall():
            scoreboard.game_over()
            still_playing = False

    screen.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The window I create in the program is 600 x 600.

```
    def has_hit_wall(self):
    return self.head.xcor() > 280 or self.head.xcor() < -280 or self.head.ycor() > 280 or self.head.ycor() < -280
```

The function above is used to detect when the snake head hits the wall. It works only when I am hitting the right or bottom of screen. If I hit the top or left it executes too early and I am not sure as to why.

[Picture of hitting top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYDVq.png)

[Picture of hitting left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zV6Q.png)

[Picture of hitting right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd5qY.png)

[Picture of hitting bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUWkv.png)

I am unsure why this happens as the coordinates are not different on any of the sides. I have tried making the coordinates bigger or smaller but it does not seem to be fixing the problem.

Comment: Without knowing what sets the `xcor` or `ycor` of `head` then there's no way we can know why this is happening. This is not a [mre]. We can only assume that what is happening is that the values are getting set before you expect them to; but you haven't indicated stepping through this in a debugger or doing any such steps on your own to try to solve this. If you don't know how to debug then I suggest [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html).

Comment: It's only one pixel difference. Change the `>` conditions for `>=`, leave the `<` as `<` and increase the value to 281. This happens because there's a pixel 0 that breaks symmetry between positive and negative coordinates. Imagine you have a 4x4 map. X coordinates will be `-1, 0, 1, 2` and you can see here how they are assymetric. Otherwise make a map with an odd number of pixels